# How can I take column of data and transform into multiple column of data based on special character

Tags: c#

I have a simple console app that reads in data like shown below in the From section. I'd like the data to be in rows like shown in the latter code snippet. What way would be easiest to do? Is there a way to output the data in console app where I can just paste into Excel. Or would it be better to paste in Excel and use VBA to solve this?

From:

```
Special Char
row1
row2
row3
row4
row5
Special Char
row1
row2
row3
row4
Special Char
row1
row2
row3
row4
Special Char
row1
row2
```

Want it to look like this

```
Special Char   Special Char   Special Char   Special Char
row1           row1           row1           row1
row2           row2           row2           row2
row3           row3           row3           
row4           row4           row4           
row5
```

**Update**
[image]

Comment: Is this helps you ? [https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/exploration/interpolated-strings-local#control-the-field-width-and-alignment-of-interpolation-expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/exploration/interpolated-strings-local#control-the-field-width-and-alignment-of-interpolation-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

```
void Main()
{
    var s = @"Special Char
row1
row2
row3
row4
row5
Special Char
row1
row2
row3
row4
Special Char
row1
row2
row3
row4
Special Char
row1
row2";



    var split = Regex.Split(s, "Special Char\r\n").Where(r => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r))
        .Select(r => r.Split(new char[] { '\n'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        .ToArray();
    
    var maxItems = split.Max(sp => sp.Length);
    

    string[,] rows = new string[maxItems,4];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < split[i].Length; j++)
        {
            rows[j,i] = split[i][j];
        }
    }


    Console.WriteLine("Special Char\tSpecial Char\tSpecial Char\tSpecial Char");    
for (int i = 0; i < maxItems; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            Console.Write($"{rows[i, j],-12}\t");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: updated op with my results

Comment: @Rod, I don't understand what you mean by your update. I already gave the solution. It outputs what you asked for.